# class function Callback is not accessed

Tags: python, python-3.x

No error when I start the script and but the callback of the class `startSacnRec` doesn't work and Visual Code give me the info "Callback is not accessed"

```
class sacnRec():

#contstruktur super().__init__(self) Elternklasse vererbung aufrufen
def __init__(self, fileName, universum):
    self.fileName = fileName    
    self.universum = universum       

def deleteFile(self):
    with open(self.fileName + '.txt','w'): pass

def packettoIntData(data):
    uniData = str(data)[1:-1]
    uniDataList = [int(s) for s in uniData.split(',')]
    return uniDataList

def writeCsv(set,data,fileName):
    with open(fileName + '.txt', "a") as file:
        file.write(str(set))
        file.write(str(data))

def startSacnRec(self):
    print("Start des Servers" + str(self.universum))
    receiver = sacn.sACNreceiver()
    receiver.start() 
    @receiver.listen_on('universe', universe=self.universum)  # listens on universe 1
    def callback(packet):  # packet type: sacn.DataPacket
        print(packet.dmxData) 
        print(packet.sourceName)
        print("test")
        #uniOneSet = [int(packet.universe),int(packet.priority),str(packet.sourceName) ]
        #print(uniOneSet)
       # uniOneDmx = packettoIntData(packet.dmxData)          
        #writeCsv(uniOneSet,uniOneDmx, name)
    
        receiver.join_multicast(1)

    time.sleep(10)  # receive for 10 seconds
    receiver.stop()
 one = sacnRec(1,1)
 one.startSacnRec()
```

I think the problem is here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGrLF.png)

Comment: I attempted to fix the indentation of the code in the question, but I'm not sure I got it all right. You may want to [edit] the question further to make sure the indentation matches what you're actually running on your own system.

Comment: in startsacnrec you need to do function call of clouser callback

Comment: Hello, i edit my problem description. thanks for help.

Answer (score -1):

Using a decorator (the `@receiver.listen_on...` part) is usually for class methods.

If you want to use a [closure](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Closures) based callback, then use `receiver.register_listener` approach.

https://github.com/Hundemeier/sacn#receiving-1